# (Indefinite) article for something that only one exists

Tags: phrase-usage, articles

Let's say there is an alarming device and it has only one light to show color. Then I could say,

> It raised a red alarm.
>
> It shows a red warning (or light).

But then, as it only has one light, there cannot be multiple alarms or warnings. Can I omit the article in those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not omit the article.

The first thing is  while there is only one light, you are referring to one time when it was lit -- that is a single alarm/warning.  The other ones may be nothing more than possible, but they will happen at different times.

You can make clear which time you are referring to, by context or the like, but then the second is that this sentence structure would require you to use the article "the" instead of "a."